# Como saber que accion se ejecuto al usar updateOrCreate?

Tags: php, laravel

Cuando utilizo el upsert `updateOrCreate`, por ejemplo

```
$flight = Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99, 'discounted' => 1]
);
```

Existe algun metodo asociado o alguna otra forma para saber si la accion tomada fue creacion o actualizacion? Algo asi como:

```
$flight->actionTaken;
```

Comment: Hola, sí es posible, aquí puedes ver varios ejemplos https://stackoverflow.com/a/49350664/6119009

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar **wasRecentlyCreated**

```
$flight->wasRecentlyCreated;
```

este te devuelve un valor booleano, si crea un nuevo recurso devuelve *true*